Does Nancy know the information that FAA wants to know?
From SpaceX launch of Polaris Dawn mission delayed again, indefinitely on hold 0:05

On the launch pad at Kennedy Space Center, Polaris Dawn may be waiting
for much longer. WESH 2's Nancy Alvarez tells us what the FAA wants to know. Grounded, following a failed drone landing for a Starlink
mission, the FAA is telling SpaceX to halt all Falcon 9 flights until
further notice.

Does "WESH 2's Nancy Alvarez tells us what the FAA wants to know." have the same meaning as "WESH 2's Nancy Alvarez tells us something that the FAA wants to know."?
Nancy Alvarez probably did not know the relating information, and the presenter seemingly meant "Nancy Alvarez tells us that the FAA wants to know something about this mission"

You'll have to provide more context because I'm not going to watch a video of uncertain source, length, or contents. It might be introducing a reporter (WESH 2's Nancy Alvarez) who is going to tell us things that the FAA previously wanted to know but have now found out; it might be something else. Why don't you watch it yourself and see what happens?

The one thing it doesn't mean is what you suppose it might   mean, that Nancy A. is telling us the basic fact "that the FAA wants to know something". It means, as DJClayworth says in the answer, probably that Nancy A. will tell us about the FAA's questions, but possibly (though highly unlikely) that she has some information the FAA is seeking.

@Stuart F You are not a language learner, so sometimes maybe don't understand my intention.

There are two possible interpretations of this:

Nancy Alvarez tells us what questions the FAA want answered.

and

Nancy Alvarez tells us the answers to the questions the FAA is asking.

There is insufficient context to determine which is meant. However it is unlikely that a reporter knows answers to questions when the FAA doesn't, so it's probably the first.
